# Зачем нужны ссылки на интерфейсы

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Есть программа, в которой я использую ссылки на интерфейсы. Грубо говоря. У меня есть интерфейс `IRoom`, в которой есть интерфейс `ITableList`, с методами взаимодействия со столами, в котором есть интерфейс `ITable` со всеми свойствами стола.

1. Зачем разработчики сделали так, если можно было использовать объекты в объектах?
2. Где разработчики реализовали все методы интерфейсов, если я работаю лишь с ссылками на интерфейс?
   Просто необходимо реализовать подобное приложение и пытаюсь понять, зачем в данном сделали именно так.

[image: Это интерфейс Позиций]
Это интерфейс Позиций

[image: Это интерфейс Список позиций взаимодействия с Позициями]
Это интерфейс Список позиций взаимодействия с Позициями

[image: Это интерфейс всего, там же и есть взаимодействие со Списком позиций]
Это интерфейс всего, там же и есть взаимодействие со Списком позиций

[image: Это код взаимодействия sec - ISecurity, Positions - IPositionList, GetLast.... - IPosition]
Это код взаимодействия sec - ISecurity, Positions - IPositionList, GetLast.... - IPosition

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под словосочетанием «ссылки на интерфейсы»? Можно привести пример?

Comment: Действительно, что за зверь такой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Потому что под интерфейсом может скрываться экземпляр любого класса, реализующего этот интерфейс, и при необходимости его можно легко подменить (например в целях тестирования или чтобы изменить поведение). В случае с экземпляром конкретного класса подменить его на экземпляр какого-то другого класса уже нельзя.
2. Под каждым интерфейсом скрывается какая-то конкретная реализация, в которой и определены необходимые методы. Например:

   ```
   interface IFoo 
   {
       IBar Bar { get;set; }

      // прочие свойства и методы
   }

   class Foo : IFoo
   {
       public IBar Bar { get; set; }
   }



   var foo = new Foo();
   // здесь мы присваиваем свойству Bar переменную класса Bar, в котором
   // уже определены все методы, указанные в интерфейсе IBar
   foo.Bar = new Bar();
   ```

Comment: Почему не `public IBar Bar { get; set; }`? - не скомпилируется же

Comment: @Андрей да, разумеется, вы правы. Просто пришлось откатить вашу правку, так как писал свою

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая штука, [Принцип инверсии зависимостей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9) - про него можно легко нагуглить. Интерфейсы являясь абстракцией и помогают реализовывать этот принцип. Используя интерфейсы программу можно сделать более гибкой и легко тестируемой. Интерфейс это контракт - он гарантирует, что класс реализующий его будет содержать описанные в интерфейсе методы - так что вся реализации интерфейсов находится непосредственно в классах.
Ну как это делается, вам уже в соседнем ответе рассказали. Не буду повторяться.
То что вы поняли под ссылкой на интерфейс - это просто конструкция языка, подразумевающая, что в этом поле будет хранится ссылка на любой класс реализующий этот интерфейс.